# How do I remove a leading or trailing blank space in file name with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, trim

I'm basically trying to trim() any filenames that have a leading or trailing space at the end of the name. This is the code I've got so far

```
$foldersToCheck = "$env:userprofile\documents", "$env:userprofile\pictures", "$env:userprofile\desktop"
foreach ($folder in $foldersToCheck) {
    get-childitem -path $folder -recurse | foreach-object {
        if ($_.name.startswith(" ") -or $_.name.endswith(" ")) {
            $newName = $_.name.trim()
            rename-item -path $_ -newName $newname
        }
    }
}
```

If I create a test file (c:\users\someusername\desktop\ test.txt), then I receive this error

```
rename-item : Cannot rename because item at ' test.txt' does not exist.
    At line:6 char:13
    +             rename-item -path $_ -newName $newname
    +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

So, it looks like it found the file that needs to be renamed, but then says it doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that PowerShell resolves `$_` to just the file name when attempting to convert it to a string it can bind to `-Path`.

Explicitly pass the *full path* of the file and it'll work:

```
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname
```

Alternatively, pipe the `$_` file object to `Rename-Item` and PowerShell will automatically figure out that it needs to bind `$_.FullName` to `Rename-Item`'s `-LiteralPath` parameter:

```
$_ |Rename-Item -NewName $newname
```

---

You can also turn the whole loop into a single pipeline, and then take advantage of a pipeline-bound expression against `-NewName`:

```
$foldersToCheck |Get-ChildItem -Recurse |Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Trim() }
```

If the existing `Name` and the `-NewName` values are the same, `Rename-Item` will just leave the files alone anyway :)

Comment: Worked like a charm. THank you!

Comment: @MysteriousMuffins Great, you're welcome! I also added a single-pipeline example if it helps :)